# steps of creating webpage in bangla

Tags: html, web

Language Code is BN
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp?output=print

I have tried to create a page that will be in Bengali
But as output I get something ???????????

here is what I have tried

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="bn">
<head>
<title > ডোমেইন সার্ভিস </title>

</head>
<body>

 ডোমেইন সার্ভিস
</body>

</html>
```

Would you please let me know the steps I will need to create a page in Bengli.

Answer (score 3):

The language code has nothing to do with the characters available to you. It is used for such things as screen reader pronunciation dictionary selection, search engine filtering and automated translation services.

To use the characters you want you need to:

1. Save the document in a character encoding which supports the characters you want to use. In general, this should be UTF-8. How you do this depends on your choice of editor. If you do any server side programming then you need to ensure that you track what encoding your data is in and keep it in encodings that support the characters you need. Badly configured databases are a common way to break your encoding.
2. Tell the browser what encoding you are using. This should be done via the `Content-Type` HTTP response header. (`Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8`). How you set this depend on which web server you are using and if you are doing any server side programming. You should, additionally, specify the encoding in the document itself via a meta element: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting utf-8 meta tag, and save your file in utf-8 format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Krasimir. Its working fine . I have also a page in php . do I need to follow the same steps ?  putting utf-8 meta tag, and saving the file in utf-8 forma? Btw the page is not database driven. I am now hard coding the php page

Comment: Please up my comment. If I was useful

Comment: Yes follow this steps for others files.